# Issue with MongoDB array aggregation and grouping by key in array of objects

Tags: arrays, mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregate

Considering an array like the one below which i'm trying to group by date and sum the durations:

```
[
  {
    "allDates": [
      {
        "duration": 153,
        "date": "2021-10"
      },
      {
        "duration": 20,
        "date": "2021-11"
      },
      {
        "duration": 181,
        "date": "2021-11"
      },
      {
        "duration": 180,
        "date": "2021-11"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

I'm trying to achieve a sum of the duration but grouped by the dates.
This is what i've tried so far:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $addFields: {
      durations: {
        $arrayToObject: {
          $map: {
            input: "$allDates",
            as: "allDate",
            in: {
              k: {
                $toString: "$$allDate.date"
              },
              v: {
                $sum: {
                  $map: {
                    input: "$allDates",
                    as: "kv",
                    in: {
                      $cond: {
                        if: {
                          $eq: [
                            {
                              $toString: "$allDate.date"
                            },
                            {
                              $toString: "$$kv.k"
                            }
                          ]
                        },
                        then: "$$kv.duration",
                        else: 0
                      }
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      },
      
    }
  }
])
```

Unfortunately the result i get is:

```
[
  {
    "allDates": [
      {
        "date": "2021-10",
        "duration": 153
      },
      {
        "date": "2021-11",
        "duration": 20
      },
      {
        "date": "2021-11",
        "duration": 181
      },
      {
        "date": "2021-11",
        "duration": 180
      }
    ],
    "durations": {
      "2021-10": 534,
      "2021-11": 534
    }
  }
]
```

So it's adding them all up for every key instead of for each one separately, what am i missing here?

Basically I'm expecting to get:

```
...
"durations": {
      "2021-10": 153, 
      "2021-11": 381 
}
```

Comment: What do you like to get as result?

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit `"durations": {"2021-10": 153, "2021-11": 381 }` basically. So to add the durations per date and not all of them. Edited the question to reflect that.

Answer (score 1):

Try this one:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $unwind: "$allDates"
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$allDates.date",
      duration: {
        $sum: "$allDates.duration"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: null,
      durations: {
        $push: {
          k: "$_id",
          v: "$duration"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      _id: 0,
      durations: {
        $arrayToObject: "$durations"
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/IySXYWvQAa4)